# How to add the strings in the same line one after other instead of new line?

Tags: bash, unix

im greping few of the strings and writing it into text file, but its writing it in new line every time, is there a way we can print it in same line after a tab space? below is my code, thank you in advance.

```
grep -oi "Part.*Time.*[0-9]*" $EachLineFile | grep -oi "Pa..: [0-9]" >> $String
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` prints a newline after each match. 
You can remove is using `tr`.

Try something as the following:

`grep -oi "Part.*Time.*[0-9]*" $EachLineFile | grep -oi "Pa..: [0-9]" | tr '\r\n' '\t' >> $String`

`tr '\r\n' '\t'` removes any newline and put a `tab` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I find `tr` a bit dangerous, especially if you do not know what you have in the greped line. But the previous answer from @Davide would work in situations you are fully aware of the content. (It would take all \r and change them to \t and all \n and do the same, possibly creating 2 tabs as a separator)

My suggestion is `awk`

```
grep -oi "Part.*Time.*[0-9]*" $EachLineFile | grep -oi "Pa..: [0-9]" | awk '{print}' ORS="\t"  >> $String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `paste -s`.

```
grep -oi "Part.*Time.*[0-9]*" $EachLineFile | 
  grep -oi "Pa..: [0-9]"                    |
  paste -s
```